# display関数を用いて最後にスタックのデータを表示したい

Tags: c

このような状況でmain関数末尾のforループとその中のprintf文を取り出してdisplay関数にして、呼び出すのですが、どのようにコードを書いていいかわからないです。コード例が欲しいです。

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define SIZE 5
int stack[SIZE];
int sp;

void push(int value);
int pop(void);

int main(void)
{
sp = 0;
int resp, data;

while(1){
printf("1：push 2:pop 0:end : ");
scanf("%d", &resp);

if(!resp) break;

switch(resp){
case 1: printf("push : "); scanf("%d", &data);
push( data );
break;
case 2: pop();
break;
}
printf("sp=%d\n", sp);
}
printf("\n");
for(int i=0; i<sp; i++){
printf("stack[%d]=%d \n", i, stack[i]);
}

return 0;
}

void push(int value)
{
if(sp >= SIZE){
printf("スタックが満杯で入りませんでした\n");
}else{
stack[sp++] = value;
}
}

int pop(void)
{
if(sp <= 0){
printf("スタックが空で取り出せませんでした\n");
return 0;
}else{
return stack[--sp];
}
}
```

Comment: [ポーランド記法で電卓プログラムを書きたいのですが、以下訂正お願いします...](https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q10232294245)

Comment: ご質問の内容(関数への切り出し)はC言語のかなり基礎の部分ですが、そのやり方がわからない、ということでしょうか？そうだとしたら一度入門レベルの書籍をじっくり読んでみるとか、入門サイトで一通り文法を学んでみることをお勧めします。もし、そうでないのでしたら質問内容を編集して、どういうところに躓いている(コンパイルエラーが出るのであれば、そのエラー内容も含めて掲載していただく)か等をより具体的に記述していただいた方が参考になる回答が得られやすいと思います。

Answer (score 0):

コード例は @metropolis さんの紹介先を見てもらうとして、考える切っ掛けをどのようにすれば良いかを示します。

- 呼び出して処理した後の結果を必要とするか？　→　不要　→　戻り値を`void`とする
- 使用する変数や値は何か？

  - スタックをあらわす整数の配列　→　`stack[]`
  - 上記の中で先頭からの有効データ数　→　`sp`
  - ループ処理用のカウンタ　→　`i`
- パラメータとして指定する変数や値は何か？(選択肢として考え方次第：どちらでも良い)

  - 無し　→　パラメータは`void`：必要な変数`stack[]`と`sp`はグローバルに定義されている ＆ 他の`push()`/`pop()`関数でもそれらは指定していない
  - `int []`(stack[])と`int`(sp)をパラメータとして指定　→　拡張性・汎用性を考慮して処理対象をパラメータで指定できるようにする
- スタック内容の初回の表示開始位置をどうするか？(選択肢として考え方次第：どちらでも良い)

  - 必ず行の先頭から表示されるように、`display()`関数の中で初回の表示開始位置を調節する　→　`printf("\n");`を`display()`関数の`for`ループの前に入れる
  - `display()`関数はスタック内容表示に特化し、初回の表示開始位置調整は呼び出す側に任せる　→　`display()`関数は`for`ループだけにする
- `main()`関数の中で呼び出す自作の関数は、その前の`void push(int value);`と`int pop(void);`のようにあらかじめプロトタイプ宣言しておく
- 上記内容に合わせて`display()`関数を作成し、スタック内容表示処理を移動させる
- 元々のスタック内容表示処理の位置に`display()`関数を呼び出す処理を挿入する